# Are all events of a random variable disjoint?

Tags: probability, random-variables

In reference to an introductory probability class I was bothered by the fact that we can easily sum over all values of the probability (mass/density) function of a random variable, usually as:
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N} P(X=a_{i})$, without analyzing whether each of the events for each $a_i$ are disjoint. How do we know that the events for each value $a_i$ that random variable $X$ assumes are disjoint? The same goes for multiple random variables, where we sum over all values for $X$ and $Y$ and assume that the joint probability (mass/density) function $f_{xy}$ has disjoint events for each value $(a_i,b_i)$ that $X=a_i$ and $Y={b_i}$ assume.
To me it seems plausible to say that for each value that a random variable assumes it corresponds to a unique distinct event that is disjoint from all the other events that are defined for different values that the random variable can assume, mathematically: $(A_a \cap A_b = \emptyset : X=a, X=b)$ where $A_a$ and $A_b$ are events that correspond to values $a$ and $b$ of random variable $X$.
Unfortunately I could not find any proof of this.
There is a similar post of this, but it only addresses a single random variable and not multiple random variables, additionally, it hasn't even been answered.
[disjoint subset of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291832)

Thanks!

Comment: The events $\{X= a\}$ and $\{X=b\}$ are disjoint if $a \neq b$. I don't understand what proof you need.

Comment: Well, could it be possible that the two events $A_a$ and $A_b$ share some outcomes and therefore are not disjoint, even though $A_a$ yields $X=a$ and $A_b$ yields $X=b$. That's what I'm wondering. And what about two random variables: does ($A_a \cap A_b = \emptyset : (X=a_x, Y=a_y), (X=b_x, Y=b_y))$ also hold?

Comment: No, it is not possible that events $\{X=a\}$ and $\{X=b\}$ intersect if $a\neq b$, by definition of a random variable as a mapping from sample space to real numbers. I guess you study some boring formal measure-theoretical course of probability theory that kills intuition, if you have such questions.